# Excel - How do I find all relevant rows by typing unique invoice# listed Col A

Tags: excel-2007

I have a Worksheet with 10 columns and data range from A1:J55.  Col A has the invoice # and rest of the columns have other demographic data. Goal is to type the invoice number on a cell and display all the rows matching the invoice number from col A.

Besides auto filter function, the only thing comes to my mind is VBA. Please advice what is the best way to get the data. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'm pretty proud of this one. Again avoiding VBA, this one uses the volatile formula OFFSET to keep moving its VLOOKUP search down the table until it's found all matches. Just make sure you paste enough rows of the formula that if there are many matches, there's room for all of them to appear. If you put a border around your match area then it would be clear if you ever ran out of room and needed to copy down the formula some more.

Again, in the main section, it's just a single formula (using index):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$J$200,$M3,MATCH(N$2,$A$1:$J$1,0)),"")
```

This gets to be so simple because the hard work of the lookup is done by an initial column which looks up the next row that matches the invoice number. It has the formula:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH($L$2,OFFSET($A$1:$A$200,M2,0),0)+M2," ")
```

Here is the working example that goes with those formulas:

[image]

Let me know if you need any further description of how it works, but it mostly uses the same rules as above so that it's robust in copying and moving around.

I've uploaded the Excel file so you can play with it, but everything you need to reproduce this feature should be in this solution.

[Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzfY1xYjsjYbYm1RNHNKVHNNbFE/edit?usp=sharing) - Click link and hit `Ctrl+S` to download and open in Excel.

Comment: Alain, Thank you so much. I tried and it worked. I am extremely thankful for providing me the formual with examples and also attaching the excel worksheet.    I added a subtotal to count the total number of rows matched.  Formula =subtotal(3,N2:n20)  resulted to 16 rows, where as it should result ot 5 rows.  Please advise.  Thanks

Comment: I appreciate all your support.  Following formula applied and got the correct result - =(SUBTOTAL(3,BC3:BC584))-(COUNTBLANK(BC3:BC584))

Comment: @AnjiChoksi You're welcome, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure to accept the answer if you're satisfied with it :)

Answer (score 0):

A popular solution to this problem is a simple VLookup. Lookup the invoice the user types in on the table A1:J55, and then return an adjascent column's data.

Here's an example of it working:

[image]

The formula in the highlighted cell is:

```
=VLOOKUP($L3,$A:$J,MATCH(N$2,$1:$1,0),FALSE)
```

What's nice about this formula is you only need to type it once and then you can copy it across and it'll automatically pick out the correct column of the table (that's the match part). The rest is very simple:

- The first part says lookup value `$L3` (the invoice number typed in),
- The second part says look it up in range `$A:$J` (which is where your table is located). I've shown how you can select the entire columns `$A:$J` so that you can add and remove data without worrying about adjustin the range in your lookups. (Excel takes care of optimizing the formula so that unused cells aren't checked)
- The third part picks the column from which the resulting data will be drawn once a matching row is found.
- The `FALSE` part is an indication that the invoice number must match *exactly* (no approximate matching allowed)
- The `$` signs ensure that fixed ranges like the location of your source table (`$A:$J`) and your lookup value ($L3) don't get automatically changed as you copy the formula across for multiple columns.

The formula is pretty easy to adapt if you want to move around your table and the area where you do your lookup. Here's an example:

[image]

**Bonus**

If you want to add a little spiff, you can add a dropdown to the Invoice # field so that the user gets auto-completion and the option to browse existing values like so:

[image]

Comment: Gah I didn't read the question well enough. You want to return all matching rows, and this only displays the first match. Put too much effort in to delete it though so, give me a while to see if I can redeem myself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for revising and providing an elobrated version of pulling not only unique invoice, but all the rows corresponding to the unique invoice #